# AirPrint for iPhone works but not iPad Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode, swift, airprint

I have looked at the other questions that are similar through search but the coding is different and doesn't help me. I have the below code that prints local pdf's beautifully in the iPhone simulator, but it will not work in the iPad simulator. The button does nothing and this error is in the control log: WARNING: Calling -[UIPrintInteractionController presentAnimated:completionHandler:] on iPad

This is Xcode 6.3

```
 @IBAction func print(sender: AnyObject) {
    var pdfLoc = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Drop-Withdrawal Form 09-22-14", ofType:"pdf")!)
    // 1
    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()!
    // 2
    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)!
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General
    printInfo.jobName = "print Job"
    printController.printInfo = printInfo
    // 3


    printController.printingItem = pdfLoc
    // 4
    printController.presentAnimated(true, completionHandler: nil) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
// 4
 printController.presentAnimated(true, completionHandler: nil)
```

use (assuming you want to use a barButtonItem to print from):

```
printController.presentFromBarButtonItem(printButton, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

if you want to use a regular UIButton from inside the view then use:

```
printController.presentFromRect(CGRect, inView:, animated:, completionHandler:)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also make sure to have the printer simulator installed so that you can test your output.